# Unable to print integer value using Response.Write()

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, integer, response

I have following code that prints some list. The list is printing but the value of integer variable i is not printing.

```
<%
int i = 1;
try
{
    foreach (LElement r in LElements)
    {
        Response.Write("<br/><div style=\"font-size:small\">");
        Response.Write("Element "+i+"="+r.name);
        Response.Write("</div>");
        i++;
    }
    Response.Write("<br/>");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Response.Write("Error");
}
%>
```

Its just printing

Element = ABC

Element = XYZ

and so on...

Resulting HTML is somewhat like this:

```
<br/><div style="font-size:small">Element = ABC</div>
<br/><div style="font-size:small">Element = XYZ</div>
<br/><div style="font-size:small">Element = PQR</div><br/>
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Why does your output have a `:` where the code puts a `=` ?

Comment: Your output doesn't match your code, so you must be missing something, somewhere (= instead of : as a delimiter).

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML and post that,

Comment: I edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: That `int i = 1;` looks tacked onto the code sample - is this the actual code you're using? =)

Comment: Running the code here works fine. Are you sure you've tried Ctrl+F5 to refresh your page and get latest version as it may be showing a cached version with incorrect logic?

Comment: no I am trying it from days. Even clearing all histories and running on different servers. The result is always same.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Is this your actual code or just a silly example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Response.Write(String.Format("Element {0} = {1}", i, r.name));
```

Comment: Just a different way of doing things, does not explain the initial results.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried reproducing your issue and can't so I am guessing either your sample code is quite different from your real code or something deeper is going on? This is what I've done and works OK so you could take this as a starting point and tell us if it works any more than your code and might highlight any mistakes you have made?

```
<%    
    string[] data = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "XYZ" };
    int i = 1;

    try
    {
        foreach(string item in data)
        {
            Response.Write("<br/><div style=\"font-size:small\">");
            Response.Write(String.Format("Element {0} = {1}", i, item));
            Response.Write("</div>");
            i++;
        }
        Response.Write("<br/>");
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        Response.Write("Error");
    }
%>
```

P.S. I've wrapped the output into a `String.Format` which will ensure it gets converted to a string correctly.

Comment: Thanks Belogix.. it worked.. +1 to you... marked Zarathos because he answered first :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Response.Write(String.Format("Element {0} = {1}", i, r.name));
```

**Edit:** Zarathos was ahead of me :)

Comment: Thanks Abbas and +1 to you because it worked. Since as you said Zarathos was ahead of you so I marked his answer